# How can i add elements to a PriorityQueue of Java Collections that are of different type?

Tags: java, collections

I want to add string and integer elements into a Priority Queue. However,after adding string elements and then integer, the program breaks and gives me error as following:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Is it not allowed to have values of multiple types in a single PriorityQueue?
What could be the other way around?

My PriorityQueue looks like this:

```
PriorityQueue queue = new PriorityQueue();
```

Element to add is as following:

```
public void addElementToQueue(Object obj) {
        queue.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5221149)

Comment: Use the [`PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) constructor to create a `PriorityQueue<Object>`, using a `Comparator` of your own implementation that knows how to compare a `String` with an `Integer`.

Comment: Two questions - 1. Why do you want to add String and Integers in the same Queue? 2. Can you share complete code and stacktrace etc?

Comment: *Curious:* What comes first, `Foo` or `42`?

Comment: @Andreas: I added the string values first and then the integer one.

Comment: if i add the following data:   priorityQueue.add("Foo");
  priorityQueue.add("Bar");
  priorityQueue.add(2);
  priorityQueue.add(1);
  priorityQueue.add(3);
  priorityQueue.add(4);   What do you expect in the response ?

Comment: @Priyesh I wasn't asking about the order you add values to the queue, but in what *priority order* you want the values *returned*, e.g. which has higher priority, `Foo` or `42`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know know what logic do you want to follow but it will look like the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Object> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Object>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            //Your own comparison logic
            return 0;
        }
    });
    priorityQueue.add("Bar");
    priorityQueue.add(2);
    priorityQueue.add(1);
    priorityQueue.add(3);
    priorityQueue.add(4);
    priorityQueue.add("Foo");
    System.out.println(priorityQueue);
}
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks